# How to get text from the tag with Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

There is the text description of the captcha i need to get. But I can`t get it with BeautifulSoup. Please help to fix it.

When I running the code: "None" is result.

```
import os, urllib.request, requests, datetime, time, random, ssl, json, codecs, csv, urllib
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


chromedriver = "chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1050, 740)
driver.get("https://www.inipec.gov.it/cerca-pec/-/pecs/companies")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox']/div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark']"))).click()
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find('div',{'class':'rc-imageselect-desc-wrapper'})
print (title)
driver.quit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the content you're looking for are on different `iframe` you need another switch to frame

```
.....
time.sleep(5)
# go to parent or top frame
driver.switch_to.default_content()
iframe = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe[title="recaptcha challenge"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
#title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.rc-imageselect-desc-wrapper strong') # cars
title = driver.find_element_by_class_name('rc-imageselect-desc-wrapper') # Select all images with cars.....
print(title.text)

# with BeautifulSoup
#html = driver.page_source()
#soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
#title = soup.find('div',{'class':'rc-imageselect-desc-wrapper'})
#print (title)
```